# Duplicate a project

Tags: android, ios, eclipse, xcode, duplicates

I just finished designing the free version of my app. Now my task is to develop the pro version
and I wondered how to create a copy of my app with a new bundle identifier. can somebody light my questions? I'd like to know it for Xcode and Eclipse.

GUYS: why -1 ;D

Comment: no actually not, I mean, how do people realize two different versions of their apps? It would be easy when it was just an update (= same bundle identifier), but the same app with a new bundle identifier is not broad but actually very specific.

Comment: From the command line, "grep -R my.bundle.identifier ." (while in the directory with your Xcode project). That will tell you where the identifier appears and you could change it.

Comment: ah so i actually only copy and paste my root directory, open the duplicated project and change the bundle identifier in the described way? how to do this with eclipse?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Practice: How to handle code differences for iOS App when creating free and paid version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22568483/best-practice-how-to-handle-code-differences-for-ios-app-when-creating-free-and)

Answer (score 1):

its easy. select the project in the project explorer, and click copy. then right click in some empty space in the project explorer and click paste.

it will make you rename the project.

open the newly created duplicate, and right click the package itself, then refactor>rename

rename your package as so"com.company.newpackage"

it may ask you if you want to update your code, click yes.

now go into the manifest for the newly duped package and find any remaining references to the old package, thes have to be updated manually.

i use find/replace to change the last word of all the packages at once, since thats the only one that should be different.

set it to the same as your package as so"com.company.newpackage"

and your done!

this is for eclipse btw. enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on the project and select copy and than past it again. 
Then just change all the packages and you have a duplicate!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Android Library Projects here: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects

Creating library to hold the common code between the two versions of the app can save a lot of time down the road when making modifications/fixing bugs.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right Click on project > copy
2. In project explorer Right click then paste
3. Right Click on project and rename your package name